# Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail") is not working

Tags: asp-classic

I have server with IIS7. A lot of sites that hosted on it. 
We tried to implement email sending on one of the classic asp site. 
I know it is not difficult at all. 
But it can't create cdonts activeX object. (error '800a01ad'. ActiveX component can't create object) 
It is working well on the rest sites.
I tried to copy two pages on the different site that is located on same server and code is working well. 
So what may cause this type of problem?

Comment: Is the site working an a different app pool or under a different user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, It was resolved. I switched site's application pool to 32bit. It was 64 before.
cdonts is 32 bit dll. Thanks.

Comment: CDONTS is really, really old.  Is there a reason your not using CDOSYS.  I'm not even sure if CDONTS is supported on 2008.

Comment: It works well on 2008. Hmm, I'm not asp developer. Clients asked me to fix the problem and I did it. It seems CDONTS has simplier syntax then CDOSYS. So I left it as is and it is working well now.